# How to Integrate a Pyomo optimisation model into a Java web application?

Tags: java, optimization, model, pyomo

I'm new on optimization models, I have an optimisation model written in Python (Pyomo) and a web application written in Java (Windows machine and Eclipse IDE). I need to integrate the Python model into the Java application. I have tried to translate Python model into Google OR-Tools but they seem to be different each others. I have read also something about OptimJ but it seem to be not avaible.

Is there a way to simply interface the Java web application to Pyomo model?

Is it necessary to translate the model into Java? If yes, which optimization model is suitable to use?

Thanks

Comment: Not easy to give advice without knowing the application, model and your skill set. There are ways to call Python from Java (passing data may require some work; may be storing data in a RDBMS can help). Translating the model into a Java based modeling tool is another route. That needs to be done by hand, so not quick or easy if the model is large or complex.

Comment: It is also relevant what class of optimization problem you have (LP, MILP, MINLP, NLP) and what solution algorithm you plan to use to solve it (especially if it is a licensed algorithm)

Comment: The optimization problem is MIP and the solver is cbc.exe, both have free licence or are open source. The application istead is a Maven project. I'm now trying to call Python from Java using Jython, I think this is easier than the translate the algorith into Java because I'm not good in Operating researce

Comment: @Electra If you don't want to work on the model, your way is the simplest. You don't need to use Jython, you can call Python as a process from Java, python writes the answer to database or file, then you read from there.

Comment: Thank you, I have done in this way, with a process, and send data with a json object.

Comment: Can you share the process I am also stuck at that place?